# R error: level sets of factors are different

Tags: r

I'm working on an assignment practicing Logistic Regression models.  Our data is on shots made in NBA games and each row includes a column for what team the player making the shot belongs to and a column for who the home team was.

I am trying to add a column with TRUE/FALSE values based on whether or not the shot was taken by the home team, based on some example code we were provided.

`df$home.advntg <- df$Team == df$Home`

However I keep getting the error: "Error in Ops.factor(df$Team, df$Home) :
level sets of factors are different"

When I check the columns with `str()` however these are the results:

`str(df$Team)` : "Factor w/ 30 levels "ATL","BKN","BOS",..: 7 16 27 3 24 1 10 8 12 12 ..."

`str(df$Home)` : "  Factor w/ 30 levels "ATL","BKN","BOS",..: 7 20 27 5 28 1 10 8 1 12 ..."

The data I'm using is a subset of a much larger dataset which covered shots made from 1997 to 2020.  The code worked on the original data, so something about how I've reduced it to just the 2020 shots is probably responsible.  The dates of the games are in YMD format, so to filter down to just 2020 I ran:

```
df0 <- read_csv("NBA Shot Locations 1997 - 2020.csv")
df0$Year <- substr(df0$"Game Date",1,4)
df <- filter(df0, Year == 2020)
df <- df[,-23]
```

When I run `str` and check the columns with the original data (for which there was no error) I get:

`str(df$Team)` : "Factor w/ 36 levels "ATL","BKN","BOS",..: 18 17 8 2 18 7 1 10 9 12 ..."

`str(df$Home)` : "Factor w/ 36 levels "ATL","BKN","BOS",..: 6 17 5 28 18 2 1 10 9 12 ..."

In both cases the Factor levels look like they're the same.  I don't really understand what the numbers being returned by the str function represent.

Comment: Hello Rachel, do `setdiff(levels(df$Team), levels(df$Home))` and `setdiff(levels(df$Home), levels(df$Team))` to see wether there are non matching levels on either side. if so, you can equal the levels doing `df$Home <-factor(df$Home, levels = union(levels(df$Home), levels(df$Team)))` and the same with df$Team. 
Also, you can set `df$Team <- as.character(df$Team)`, the same with Home, and the comparision will work.